# How to solve manager peer problem question?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, union-find

I was asked below question in google interview but could not answer it. I did google search but could not find any correct solution for this problem. Can you please help me to provide a solution for this problem?

> Design a data structure to support following functions:
>
> 1. setManager(A, B) sets A as a direct manager of B
> 2. setPeer(A, B) sets A as a colleague of B. After that, A and B will have the same direct Manager.
> 3. query(A, B) returns if A is in the management chain of B.
>    Every person only has 1 direct manager.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I think you probably left out some important information, like maybe you can't change someone's manager once it's set.

Comment: @jbapple I thought of creating a dummy parent node for PEER(A,B) but then I got stuck for case like PEER(A,B) , PEER(C,D) and then PEER(B,C).

Comment: @MattTimmermans you can ignore this scenario. This is an invalid scenario. There will be only one manager for any employee and all it's peers.

Comment: Why did you use the `union-find` tag?

Comment: I found in leetcode that this problem can be solved using union-find although no solution is provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use three hash tables 1. employee to group id mapping (emp) 2. group id to list of employees (gid) 3. group id -> manager id table (manager)

```cpp
int id = 0;
void setpeer(string A, string B) {
int id1 = 0;
int id2 = 0;
if (emp.find(A) != emp.end())
   id1 = emp[A];
if (emp.find(B) != emp.end())
   id2 = emp[B];

if (!id1 && !id2) {
    ++id;
    emp[A] = id;
    emp[B} = id;
    gid[id].push_back(A);
    gid[id].push_back(B);
} else if (!id1) {
     emp[A] = id2;
     gid[id2].push_back(A);
} else if (!id2) {
     emp[B] = id1;
     gid[id1].push_back(B);
} else {
   for(i = 0;i<gid[id2].size();i++) {
       emp[gid[id2][i]] = id1;
       gid[id1].push_back( gid[id2][i] );
  }
  if (manager.find(id2) != manager.end())
        manager[id1] = manager[id2].
  manager.erase(id2);
  gid.erase(id2);
}

void setManager(string A, string B) {
int id1, id2;
   if (emp.find(A) != emp.end())
         id1 = emp[A];
  else {
       ++id;
      emp[A] = id;
      id1 = id;
      gid[id].push_back(A);
  }
   if (emp.find(B) != emp.end())
         id2 = emp[B];
  else {
       ++id;
      emp[B] = id;
      id2 = id;
      gid[id].push_back(B);
  }
   manager[id2] = id1;
}

bool query(string A, string B) {
   int id1 = 0, id2 = 0;
   if (emp.find(A) != emp.end())
        id1 = emp[A];
   if (emp.find(B) != emp.end())
        id2 = emp[B];
   if (!id1 || !id2) //one of them does not exist
     return false;
  id2 = manager[id2];
  while(id2 != 0) {
     if (id2 == id1)
        return true;
     id2 = manager[id2];
 }
 return false;
}
```

Comment: If you were able to come up with a solution, why did you raise the question, start a bounty and then accept your own answer?

Comment: I did not come out of solution initially. After going through all answers posted by other buddies, I am able to find a solution.

Comment: Isn't this the exact same code posted in Ranju's answer, to which the bounty was awarded? Why not just accept his answer? (in addition I think this one is much less readable than other answers posted here)

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider each group of peers as a node in the hierarchy tree that represents the company management chain. We know that it's a tree because each person only has 1 direct manager.

We'll have the tree of the following form:

[image]

Quick ideas:

- `setManager` is just connecting 2 nodes (and also creating node if not already existed).
- `setPeer` is just updating a node to include the other peer (if node already existed); or creating a node for both peers (if none of the node existed); or merging 2 existing nodes (if 2 nodes were created independently for each peer).
- `query(A, B)` is just to traverse the tree upwards and check if a node on that path contains employee A.
- One extra issue: given an employee X, we need to get the access to the corresponding node (can be solved by having an extra hash table, which map from every employee to the reference of their corresponding node).

---

The code for the above idea

```
public class EmployeeManagement {
  private Dictionary < string, Node > _employeeToNode;

  public EmployeeManagement() {
    _employeeToNode = new Dictionary < string, Node > ();
  }

  public void SetManager(string manager, string employee) {
    if (!_employeeToNode.ContainsKey(manager)) {
      _employeeToNode[manager] = new Node(null, manager);
    }

    if (!_employeeToNode.ContainsKey(employee)) {
      _employeeToNode[employee] = new Node(_employeeToNode[manager], employee);
    } else {
      _employeeToNode[employee].SetManagerNode(_employeeToNode[manager]);
    }
  }

  public void SetPeer(string employeeA, string employeeB) {
    if (_employeeToNode.ContainsKey(employeeA) && _employeeToNode.ContainsKey(employeeB)) {
      if (_employeeToNode[employeeA].HasEmployee(employeeB) &&
        _employeeToNode[employeeB].HasEmployee(employeeA)) {
        return;
      }
      // Merge node of A and B if distinct
      Node newNode = _employeeToNode[employeeA];
      Node oldNode = _employeeToNode[employeeB];
      if (_employeeToNode[employeeB].EmployeeCount() > newNode.EmployeeCount()) {
        newNode = _employeeToNode[employeeB];
        oldNode = _employeeToNode[employeeA];
      }

      if (!newNode.HasManager()) {
        newNode.SetManagerNode(oldNode.GetManagerNode());
      }

      foreach(var employee in oldNode.GetEmployees()) {
        newNode.AddEmployee(employee);
      }

      _employeeToNode[employeeA] = newNode;
      _employeeToNode[employeeB] = newNode;
      foreach(var employee in oldNode.GetEmployees()) {
        _employeeToNode[employee] = newNode;
      }
    } else if (_employeeToNode.ContainsKey(employeeA)) {
      _employeeToNode[employeeB] = _employeeToNode[employeeA];
    } else if (_employeeToNode.ContainsKey(employeeB)) {
      _employeeToNode[employeeA] = _employeeToNode[employeeB];
    } else {
      // Create a new node for both A and B
      Node forAB = new Node(null, employeeA);
      forAB.AddEmployee(employeeB);
      _employeeToNode[employeeA] = forAB;
      _employeeToNode[employeeB] = forAB;
    }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Check if A is in the management chain of B
  /// </summary>
  public bool Query(string employeeA, string employeeB) {
    if (!_employeeToNode.ContainsKey(employeeA) || !_employeeToNode.ContainsKey(employeeB)) {
      return false; // no info of employee A or employee B yet
    }

    Node managersOfB = _employeeToNode[employeeB].GetManagerNode();
    while (managersOfB != null) {
      if (managersOfB.HasEmployee(employeeA)) {
        return true;
      }

      managersOfB = managersOfB.GetManagerNode();
    }

    return false; // not found A in the management chain of B
  }
}

private class Node {
  private Node _directManagers;
  private HashSet < string > _employees;

  public Node(Node directManagers, string employee) {
    _directManagers = directManagers;
    _employees = new HashSet < string > ();
    _employees.Add(employee);
  }

  public bool HasManager() {
    return _directManagers != null;
  }

  public void SetManagerNode(Node directManagers) {
    _directManagers = directManagers;
  }

  public Node GetManagerNode() {
    return _directManagers;
  }

  public void AddEmployee(string employee) {
    _employees.Add(employee);
  }

  public HashSet < string > GetEmployees() {
    return _employees;
  }

  public bool HasEmployee(string employee) {
    return _employees.Contains(employee);
  }

  public int EmployeeCount() {
    return _employees.Count;
  }
}
```

Comment: In your diagram, multiple values are in the same node. That is only possible for leaf nodes; internal nodes can only have one value

Comment: @AbhinavMathur ah you're right. That makes the problem even simpler

Comment: I updated the diagram according to the feedback

Comment: @Hung Thai foreach(var employee in oldNode.GetEmployees()) {
        newNode.AddEmployee(employee);
      }
I think in this code block you need to update map for old node employees I mean in the map oldNode employees still pointing to old Node. One more thing you might have to delete old Node.

Comment: @sachin thanks for spotting that. I updated the code to fix that case. And you were right, for certain programming languages we'll have to manually dispose the oldNode object.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have the following person class:

```cpp
struct Person {
  // we need to store the manager, obviously
  Person* manager = nullptr;
  // we also need to store the peers to assign the correct
  // manager for all when it is set for one person in the group
  shared_ptr<vector<Person*>> peerGroup = make_shared<vector<Person*>>({this});
};
```

A person, when newly created, has no manager and a peer group containing only the person itself.

Assuming A, B, etc. are not strings but `Person*`, you can implement the methods as follows:

```cpp
void setManager(Person* a, Person* b) {
  for (Person* person : *b->peerGroup) person->manager = a;
}

void setPeer(Person* a, Person* b) {
  // merge peer groups of a and b
  // by first adding b's peers to a's peer group
  // and then setting b's peer group to a's peer group
  for (Person* person : *b->peerGroup) a->peerGroup->push_back(person);
  b->peerGroup = a->peerGroup;
}

bool query(Person* a, Person* b) {
  // we want to find out if a is managed by b
  // so we go up the hierarchy, starting from a
  Person* current = a;
  while (current->manager != nullptr) {
    // stop if b is (indirect) manager of a
    if (current->manager == b) return true;
    current = current->manager;
  }
  // we reached the top of the hierarchy and did not find b
  return false;
}
```

In case you actually receive strings (like "A", "B", ...) you could just use a hashmap to see if you already created a `Person` object for this name and if not create one:

```cpp
map<string, unique_ptr<Person>> persons;

Person* getPerson(string name) {
  if (!persons.contains(name)) {
    persons[name] = make_unique<Person>();
  }
  return persons[name].get()
}
```

Comment: let say testcase is => PEER(A,B) , PEER(C,D) , PEER(B,C), Manager(E,D)   and query is QUERY(E,A). what will your code return?  Right answer is TRUE.

Comment: You seem to require to be able to first set peers and then their managers (which does not 100% make sense in the real world, as Booboo pointed out).
I edited my answer to support that (so yes, it returns true for your test case)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a single class, `Employee`, which contains an attribute/member `_manager`, which is a reference to this employees manager if any and an attribute/member '_managees', a set of all Employee instances/objects that this employee manages.

Note:  I am going exclusively by my interpretation of the problem definition, which were bullet points 1-3 and not by the OP's or any other person's interpretation. The description for setPeer is **sets A as a colleague of B. After that, A and B will have the same direct Manager.** Thus when you call setPeer(A, B), you are setting A's manager to be B's manager and that it doesn't make any sense unless B has a manager. And everyone has a manager except for the head boss, and by definition the head boss can have no peers. So perhaps A just got a promotion (or a demotion or just a lateral move to another department). It doesn't mean that every former peer of A has gotten the same promotion and now have the same new manager, too. So I see this a less-complicated problem than others are making of it.

```py
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, manager=None):
        self._name = name
        self._managees = set()
        self._manager = None # so far
        if manager:
            self.set_manager(manager) # Could be none if this is the "top dog"

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Name: {self._name}, Managed By: {self._manager._name if self._manager else ""}, Manages: {[managee._name for managee in self._managees]}'

    def get_name(self):
        return self._name

    def get_manager(self):
        return self._manager

    def get_managees(self):
        return self._managees

    def manages(self, employee):
        return employee in self._managees

    def is_managed_by(self, employee):
        return self._manager is employee

    def remove_manager(self):
        """
        We are no longer managed by anyone.
        """
        if self._manager:
            self._manager.remove_managee(self)
            self._manager = None
        return self

    def remove_managee(self, managee):
        """
        This manager no longer manages managee.
        """
        self._managees.remove(managee)
        managee._manager = None # No longer has a manager
        return self

    def set_manager(self, manager):
        if not manager:
            self.remove_manager()
            return self
        if self._manager:
            # We have an existing manager:
            self._manager.remove_managee(self)
        self._manager = manager
        manager._managees.add(self)
        return self

    def add_managee(self, managee):
        """
        This manager now manages managee.
        """
        managee.set_manager(self)
        return sell

    def set_peer(self, managee):
        assert managee._manager # Make sure managee can have a peer
        self.set_manager(managee._manager)
        return self

    @staticmethod
    def query(employee1, employee2):
        """
        Is employee1 in the management chain of employee2?
        """
        manager = employee2._manager
        while manager:
            if manager is employee1:
                return True
            manager = manager._manager
        return False


tom = Employee('Tom')
dick = Employee('Dick', tom)
harry = Employee('Harry', dick)
sally = Employee('Sally')
sally.set_manager(harry)
assert sally.is_managed_by(harry) and harry.manages(sally)
sally.set_manager(tom)
assert sally.is_managed_by(tom) and tom.manages(sally)
sally.set_peer(harry)
assert sally.is_managed_by(dick) and dick.manages(sally)
assert Employee.query(tom, harry)
assert not Employee.query(harry, dick)
print(tom)
print(dick)
print(harry)
print(sally)
```

Prints:

```None
Name: Tom, Managed By: , Manages: ['Dick']
Name: Dick, Managed By: Tom, Manages: ['Harry', 'Sally']
Name: Harry, Managed By: Dick, Manages: []
Name: Sally, Managed By: Dick, Manages: []
```

Comment: let say testcase is => PEER(A,B) , PEER(C,D) , PEER(B,C), Manager(E,D)   and query is QUERY(E,A). what will your code return?  Right answer is TRUE.

Comment: @sachin **I am going exclusively by my interpretation of the problem definition, which were bullet points 1-3 and not by the OP's or any other person's interpretation.** The description for `setPeer` is **sets A as a colleague of B. After that, A and B will have the same direct Manager**.  Thus when you call setPeer(A, B), you are setting A's manager to be B's manager and that it doesn't make any sense unless B has a manager. Perhaps A just got a promotion. It doesn't mean that every former peer of A has gotten the same promotion and now have the same new manager, too.

Comment: @sachin I have updated my answer to add a note explaining my approach. Take if for what it is. If  you think it's the wrong approach, then I believe you have not fully defined the problem as given to you in your interview with your points 1 through 3. My approach represents a real-world situation. In the real world nobody would make A a peer of B if B does not have a manager because B is then the top boss and by definition cannot have a peer.